# d3.js Upgrading Force layout from v3 to v4

Tags: javascript, d3.js, layout

I am upgrading a d3 visualization that was built using d3 v3's force layout to d3 v4+. Here's the block of code that I'm trying to find the v4 equivalents.

```js
var nodes = {
"Node1":{"name":"Node1","type":"source","nodeType":-1,"size":1,"tooltip":[]},
"Node2":{"name":"Node2","type":"target","nodeType":-1,"size":1,"tooltip":[]},
"Node3":{"name":"Node3","type":"target","nodeType":-1,"size":1,"tooltip":[]}};

var links = [
{"source":{"name":"Node1","type":"source","nodeType":-1,"size":1,"tooltip":[]},
"target":{"name":"Node2","type":"target","nodeType":-1,"size":1,"tooltip":[]},
"sourcetype":-1,"targettype":-1,"relationship":"OWNS","relGroup":"relGroup0","relIndex":1,"toolTip":[],
"thickness":10,"size":1,"multiLinkCount":1,"multiLinkIndex":0,"relCount":1},
{"source":{"name":"Node1","type":"source","nodeType":-1,"size":1,"tooltip":[]},
"target":{"name":"Node3","type":"target","nodeType":-1,"size":1,"tooltip":[]},
"sourcetype":-1,"targettype":-1,"relationship":"OWNS","relGroup":"relGroup0","relIndex":1,"toolTip":[],
"thickness":1,"size":1,"multiLinkCount":2,"multiLinkIndex":0,"relCount":1},
{"source":{"name":"Node3","type":"target","nodeType":-1,"size":1,"tooltip":[]},
"target":{"name":"Node1","type":"source","nodeType":-1,"size":1,"tooltip":[]},
"sourcetype":-1,"targettype":-1,"relationship":"OWNS","relGroup":"relGroup0","relIndex":1,"toolTip":[],
"thickness":3,"size":1,"multiLinkCount":2,"multiLinkIndex":1,"relCount":1}]
;

var linkGravity = 0.1;
var linkFriction = 0.9;
var linkDistance = 100;
var linkCharge = -400;
var chargeDistance = 1000;
var linkStrength = 0.5;
var width = 400;
var height = 400;


var force = d3.layout.force()
            .nodes(d3.values(nodes))
            .links(links)
            .linkStrength(linkStrength)
            .linkDistance(linkDistance)
            .gravity(linkGravity)
            .friction(linkFriction)
            .chargeDistance(chargeDistance)
            .charge(linkCharge)
            .size([(width), (height)])
            .start();
```

Here's what I've been able to figure out based on going through similar questions on SO and reading the docs:

```js
//d3.layout.force() 
//.nodes(d3.values(nodes))
d3.forceSimulation(d3.values(nodes))

//.links(links)
//.linkStrength(linkStrength)
//.linkDistance(linkDistance)
.force('link',d3.forceLink().links(links).distance(linkDistance).strength(linkStrength))

//.gravity(linkGravity)
//declared before d3.forceSimulation
//var forceX = d3.forceX(width / 2).strength(linkGravity)
//var forceY = d3.forceY(height / 2).strength(linkGravity)
.force('x', forceX)
.force('y',  forceY)

//.friction(linkFriction)
.velocityDecay(linkFriction)

//.charge(linkCharge) - not sure about this one
.force('charge',d3.forceManyBody().strength(linkCharge))

//.size([(width), (height)])
.force("center", d3.forceCenter(width/2,height/2))

//.start() - removed as not needed anymore
```

I think I got most of it but I'm not sure about .chartDistance - is it related to v4's d3.forceManyBody().distanceMax()  or is it related to .force('collide', d3.forceCollide().radius(chargeDistance))?

Also, verification on my conversion would be appreciated, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in d3 v3, [documentation](https://d3-wiki.readthedocs.io/zh_CN/master/Force-Layout/) on chargeDistance: "If distance is specified, **sets the maximum distance over which charge forces are applied**. If distance is not specified, returns the current maximum charge distance, which defaults to infinity. "

To me that strongly implies that d3.forceManyBody().distanceMax() is the right answer.